# Excel - Date string to date and time. As well as convert to RSA time. (UTC + 2 hours)

Tags: excel, datetime, time, timestamp

I have a date format column I am not familiar with and am trying to convert:

'August 16, 2016 10:16:53 PM PDT' in text to UTC + 2 hours to get to local South Africa time.

I have never done more than a regular date time and stripping out parts of the text is giving me errors with AM/PM etc?

Can anybody assist or direct to the same format?

Thanks,

Comment: to get a regular date time: `=--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)` then its just math to get the correct time zone.  Then format any way you want.

Comment: Thanks... So really just removing and understanding timezones.

Comment: Correct, Excel does not recognize time zones.

Comment: Ok so before I add 8 hours. (Plus the 2 to adjust for RSA) I need to format the text still. Maybe I am missing something but how do you convert it starting with Augu.... , year and time to get into an actual time format? Maybe I am missing something. I have only ever used text to columns and date formula before? I am attempting custom format

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)+TIME(10,0,0)` then format it to the desired output format.  You may need to type the formula instead of copy paste as comments sometimes add unprintable characters.

Comment: Are you able to do that in one step on your excel? Straight from string? I am still getting #VALUE! even after trying to format the result.... Apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

use this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)+TIME(10,0,0)
```

Then format it like you want.

Depending on your local settings you may need to use `;` in place of the `,` due to your local settings:

```
=LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-4)+TIME(10;0;0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I suppose my local settings or something else is preventing me from converting to text (cleaned) to the right useable format. I ended up using Qlikview (long long work around) . Thanks for the help...

Comment: @user4242750 check the data to see if there is unprintable characters on the end that would interfere.

Comment: I have it sorted but even with Qlik I had to first replace all month names with /01 /02 , replaced the "," with "/" and basically reshape the entire format then import as a #Timestamp and reformat and add10/24 hours. Perhaps my computer settings are just something I am not understanding...